# Activity for result not working

Tags: android, android-activity

We have 3 classes A, B, C. Class A call class B with `startActivityForResult` to get data from it. After it returns it depends on the data retrieved from class B, whether we will go to class C to get data to Class A. This will be done in a `onListItemClick` method.
the code below isn't working can any one tell what the problem is?

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(id);
    startManagingCursor(note);
    mpass= note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_PASS));
    theid = id
    if(mpass !=null) {
        Intent ps = new Intent(this, EnterPass.class); 
        startActivityForResult(ps,2);
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);

        startActivityForResult(i, 1);}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if(requestCode==2) { 
            if(null!=intent) {
                message=intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE"); 
                if (mpass == message) { 
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
                    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, theid);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                }
            }
            else 
        }
        if(requestCode==1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                fillData();
        }
```

Comment: `the code below isnt working` where's the code

Comment: Developers in SO are normal people, they don't have super natural powers to identify your problems without proper detail, code , stacktrace etc

Comment: StartActivityForResult works in the fashion of FIFO, if suppose say you are starting like this pattern. 
Class A---->Class B--->Class C
Data will be transmitted in same reverse manner
Class C--->Class B--->Class A.

Comment: @Manik Do you think that will going to solve his problem...

Comment: I have list of view and each one have id and password when i click on any view in the list will appear activity to enter the password from the user after check the entered password with the correct one i will open the view and after finish the editview i will retrieved data from it again So i have 2 activity used startactivityforresult and the secound one depend on the result that retrieved from the first one

Comment: Please do some work yourself to find out what your problem is. I.e. use the debugger to step through your program to narrow down where your problem is. If the application is crashing, please provide the entire stack trace. The code you have supplied does not compile at all and looks like fragments of code. Please tell us what is wrong!

Comment: yes this is framents of code that have problem because the other fragments work fine .no errors appear in the debgger.  the main problem and the main Qustion is : how can i retrived data from one activity and use this data to view another activity that will retrived result also

Comment: @Pragnani: May be, may not. Eventually I added as comment or else I would have answered it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this answer will be in Mono for Android, however it is still applicable for regular Android.

I have created 3 very simple activities. `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC`.

In `ActivityA` I start `ActivityB` by calling:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof (ActivityB));
intent.PutExtra("RowId", rowId);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Where `rowId` is the position of the list. You can easily pass more information by putting more stuff into the `Intent`.

In `ActivityB` you can grab all that information and do whatever you want with it with:

```
var data = Intent.GetStringExtra("RowId");
var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
textView.Text = data;
```

Here I just put it in a `TextView` to display the `rowId` passed from `ActivityA`. Then when I want to return from `ActivityB` with some data for `ActivityA`, I do:

```
var result = new Intent();
result.PutExtra("ActivityBResult", "myResult");
SetResult(Result.Ok, result);
Finish();
```

This data can be fetched in `ActivityA`'s `OnActivityResult` method look in `case 1`, which was the `RequestCode` I had set in the `StartActivityForResult` when I started `ActivityB`. Then I just start `ActivityC`:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Result.Ok) return;
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                var activityBData = data.GetStringExtra("ActivityBResult");
                _textView1.Text = activityBData;

                //Some logic here based on data from ActivityB

                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityC));
                intent.PutExtra("ActivityBResult", activityBData);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                var activityCData = data.GetStringExtra("ActivityCResult");
                _textView2.Text = activityCData;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In the same manner as `ActivityB` was started, `ActivityC` is started. The same way I return data from `ActivityC` as I did with `ActivityB`:

```
var result = new Intent();
result.PutExtra("ActivityCResult", "some result");
SetResult(Result.Ok, result);
Finish();
```

Which returns and jumps into `case 2` of the `switch` in `OnActivityResult` above.

Comment: nice,the same idea and the same solution this example but my app after get the result from the Activity B did not execute the next instruction that go to the activity C why!!!

Comment: You are comparing `intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE")` with `mpass`. Did you put the correct thing in your `ActivityB` so that the `MESSAGE` value is the same as `mpass`?

Comment: yes i did,  message and mpass i found it the same but when comparing it nothing execute

Comment: If they are both strings you need to do `mpass.equals(message)` because otherwise you are looking if the to object references the same instead of looking if the content of the strings are the same.